# How will I make perfect circle image using card in bootstrap 5?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

In my project, I used bootstrap v.5 cards. I wanted to make the image a perfect circle and I used bootstrap class="rounded-circle" but the output image appears oval in shape. here is my code,

```
 <img src={elonMusk} class="card-img-top rounded-circle" alt={elonMusk} />
```

How do I fix this problem ?

Comment: can u provide the image

Answer (score 5):

You can use class `ratio ratio-1x1` which is pre-defined classes in `Bootstrap-5` and if your image is not in `Square` format then you need to write single line of css code like **object-fit: cover**.

```css
.img-cover{
  object-fit: cover;
  object-position: center;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container py-4">
  <div class="row g-4 row-cols-1 row-cols-sm-2 row-cols-md-3">
    <div class="col">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="ratio ratio-1x1 rounded-circle overflow-hidden">
          <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/fcbpv.jpg?s=256&g=1" class="card-img-top img-cover" alt="Raeesh">
        </div>
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title">Raeesh Alam</h5>
          <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">View More</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

as far as I know, `rounded-circle` class is just `border-radius:50%`. So if your image dimensions are not equal (like 50 x 50). you won't get perfect circle.

You can give your image some `width` and `height` to fix it's dimensions.

like :

```
img:{
    width:50px;
    height:50px
   }
```

or

```
<img id="myImage" src=".." >

#myImage{
   width:50px;
   height:50px
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create your css code and remove bootstrap rounded class.

```
<img src="elonMusk.png" class="card-img-top"  alt="elonMusk">
```

and in css file

```
img {
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

Use the border-radius property to add rounded corners to an image. 50% will make the image circular:

Answer (score 0):

In .css:-

```
    img {
      border-radius: 50%;
    }
```

[For more follow this link](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/b/border-radius/)

Answer (score 0):

put equal height and width...

```
 <img src={elonMusk} class="card-img-top rounded-circle" alt={elonMusk} 
style={{height:"200px", width:"200px"}} />
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use card component from Bootstrap and update little code for Circle image.

Bootstrap Card Component Documentation: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/components/card/

Already updated below code snippet, i hope it'll help you out. Thank You

```css
.card .card-img-top {
  height: 140px;
  width: 140px;
}
```

```html
<!-- CSS only -->
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
  <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b6/Image_created_with_a_mobile_phone.png/640px-Image_created_with_a_mobile_phone.png" class="rounded-circle card-img-top mt-3 mx-auto img-thumbnail">
  <div class="card-body">
    <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
    <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
  </div>
</div>
```